# Objective-C – Having a TestFlight configuration to include TestFlight SDK

Tags: objective-c, testing, configuration, target, testflight

I've followed the instructions from TestFlight to duplicate the "release" configuration. Also I'm using TestFlight SDK to get live reports from my app. By doing this I had to include some TestFlight code in my application. Of course I don't want to have this code in my release version of my app.

Is there some way to only include this code in the testflight configuration (the duplicated release configuration)? The same way you can do with `#ifdef DEBUG` for the debug configuration (or do I have to create a separate target for this and only include the TestFlight SDK in that target?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can exclude code from running using `#ifdef` statements pretty easily, as we suggest it for our HockeyApp service here: http://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/client-integration/crash-reporting-on-ios-quincykit

Basically it is:

1. Add a preprocessor macro to your Xcode project for all configurations: `CONFIGURATION_$(CONFIGURATION)`
2. Then you will be able to use these lines of code to include code only for a specific configuration:

   ```
   #if defined (CONFIGURATION_Beta)
       // YOUR CODE
   #endif
   ```
3. This replace `Beta` with the name of your configuration that should include the code only

The link above provides images and more detailed text on how to do it. Since you will use that library only in your beta distribution configuration, you don't need to create another configuration besides the already created one for beta distribution.

You need to have one configuration for debug, which is for development, one for beta distribution to set the adhoc entitlements and one for app store distribution. The last two are usually variations of the release configuration.

Comment: But will the TestFlight SDK be excluded from the relase build by having another configuration?

Comment: If you don't invoke it, it will not be executed in other configurations. But the SDKs code as is will still be in the binary, if you don't exclude the files from the appstore configuration, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2270202/xcode-exclude-files-in-a-custom-configuration-better-way

Comment: I recommend accepting this answer. I followed the steps here and in links, and wrote up the details in a [blog post](http://justatheory.com/computers/os/ios/integrate-testflight-sdk.html).

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd have to create a separate build configuration and use something like `#ifdef TESTFLIGHT`. You should add a macro for that configuration so it's defined only for the TestFlight configuration.

Comment: Note: you're probably better off duplicating the debug configuration because it builds faster. The release configuration builds (if configured) the executable for multiple architectures.

Comment: Any particular reason the TestFlight team recommends (http://support.testflightapp.com/kb/tutorials/how-to-create-an-ipa-xcode-4) duplicating the release configuration then?

Comment: After some research, I think my note is wrong. Go with release instead. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

My solution to this is to have a separate branch in Git for the Testflight version which includes the SDK and calls in the code, headers, etc.

I then do all my work on the main branch and keep the Testflight branch up to date with these changes. That way I don't have to include libraries or headers that I don't use in my shipping version.

It's simpler than it sounds.

Comment: How do you keep your two branches synced? You update something on your main branch and then copy the updated code to the TestFlight branch?

Comment: I just rebase the changes. Since rebase keeps track of deletions, I usually have a master branch which is where the development goes and then the release version goes in its own branch where I've already stripped out the code I don't want. Then I just rebase the production branch on to master. I've got an example (without Testflight, though, but you'll get the idea) [here](https://github.com/Abizern/JCSSheetController)