# Must I remove TestFlight before submitting to App Store?

Tags: iphone

I am using TestFlight - must I remove all the source code from my solution or is it okay just to comment out any calls to TestFlight before submitting to App Store?

Comment: Just a short update: https://testflightapp.com/sdk/live/  states that it's OK to leave the SDK in the production releases. With the new "Testflight Live" you can now gather statistics about app usage and popularity.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The testflight library adds quite a bit of weight to your app, and it would seem sensible to remove it from your app store builds if you are not using it. Commenting out your calls is also rather cumbersome.

You can use a different build configuration which uses preprocessor definitions to prevent your testflight calls unless you have built for beta, this configuration can also exclude the test flight library from non-beta builds.

This also means that your simulator runs don't call testflight either, which is usually a good thing.

There is a good explanation of the process [here](http://justatheory.com/computers/os/ios/integrate-testflight-sdk.html) which also refers [this other question here on Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8027043/objective-c-having-a-testflight-configuration-to-include-testflight-sdk)

Comment: So it doesn't both Apple if I have TestFlight calls?

Comment: It might well do, I don't know. But if you exclude it from your builds as I suggest, you won't have a problem. It could well bother _testflight_, if your app sells a million copies and they all have the testflight takeoff on launch.

Comment: As @badcat mentions, TestFlight Live means its not fine to leave the TF SDK in your build. Additionally, I can confirm that I've had an app  appproved by Apple with TestFlight left in there.