# In Xcode, how can you check environment variables to know which build configuration or scheme you have selected?

Tags: xcode, xcode-project

From my script in "Run Script" under the Project > Target > Build Phases is there a way to know which build configuration you have run
I want to copy some private bundle files if it's the Debug build config, but not copy them if it's the Release config.  Is there a way to either set an Env Variable in the Build Config, or simply get the name of the build config when running?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
if [[ "$CONFIGURATION" == "Debug" ]]
then
    echo "Copying ./BundlePrivate b/c BuildConfiguration=$CONFIGURATION"
    ditto ./BundlePrivate/ "$TARGET_BUILD_DIR/$UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH"
else
    echo "Not copying ./BundlePrivate b/c BuildConfiguration=$CONFIGURATION"
fi
```